# Why this socket.io server doesn't response to my client program?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, socket.io

I am trying to create a trivia game where the 2 users answer a question and then the winner announced at the end. I am using `socket.io` to receive the answers.

My problem is that my `server.js` is not working properly. It seems the function `allUsershaveAnswered` is not responding when the button is pressed. I am also receiving an error `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`. I am finding difficulty in finding where the problem is

```js
$(function(){
  var socket =io();

  $('#userIdForm').submit(function () {
    console.log($('#userIdForm').val());
    socket.emit('new user', $('#userIdInput').val());
    $(gameDiv).show();
    $(logInDiv).hide();
    return false;

  });

  // in game div a series of question are displayed
  $('#questionForm').submit(function () {
   socket.emit('answer' , $('#answeredInput').val());
   $('#guessForm').hide();
   $('#questionForm').show();
   return false;
 });
 // this is called when all users have answered the question

 socket.on('allUsersHaveAnswered', function (msg) {
   $('#resultsDiv').append("The answer was:" + msg.answer + "<br>Winner:"+ msg.winner);
   $('#waitingDiv').hide();
   $('#resultsDiv').show();
 });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font: 13px Helvetica, Arial;
}

form {
  background: #000;
  padding: 3px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

form input {
  border: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 90%;
  margin-right: .5%;
}

form button {
  width: 9%;
  background: rgb(130, 224, 255);
  border: none;
  padding: 10px;
}

#messages {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#messages li {
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

#messages li:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="master.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="logInDiv">
      <h1>Create an Username</h1>
      <form id="userIdForm" action="">
        <input id="userIdInput" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div id="gameDiv" hidden>
      <h1 id="info">Answer the General Knowlegde Question</h1>
      <h2 id="info2">Once the other player has answered, you will find out who won!</h2>
      <p>Who won the English Premeier League this year?</p>
      <form id="questionForm" action="">
        <input id="answeredInput" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
      </form>
      <div id='waitingDiv' hidden>
        <p>Waiting for answers</p>
      </div>
      <div id='resultsDiv' hidden>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="/main.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

This is running on the server:

```js
// server 
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

server.listen(port, function() {
  console.log('Server listening at port %d', port);
});

//Routing
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// this is the answer

var answer = "chelsea";

var guessedanswers = {};

io.on("connection", function(socket) {
  socket.on('new user', function(id) {
    socket.userId = id;
  });
  socket.on('guess', function(guess) {
    guesses[socket.userId] = parseInt(guess);
    var numAnswers = Object.keys(guessedanswers).lenght;
    console.log("we've gotten: " + numAnswers + " guesses");
    if (numAnswers >= 2) {
      var winner = "";
      for (var userId in guessedanswers) {
        var guess = guesses[userId];
        if (guess == answer) {
          winner = userId;
        }
      }

      io.emit('allUsersHaveAnswered', {
        winner: winner,
        answer: "chelsea"
      });
    }
  });
});
```

What could be the cause, how to fix it?

Comment: What is your 404 specifically saying, can you be more verbose? Where in your client-side are you emitting `guess`? Have you tried instead of `io.emit(...)` with `socket.broadcast.emit(...)`

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo here:

```
Object.keys(guessedanswers).lenght
```

in what should be `.length`

```
Object.keys(guessedanswers).length
```

That likely means that you never get the right value for `numAnswers` so you never go into the `if (numAnswers >= 2)` conditional and thus never do `io.emit('allUsersHaveAnswers`, ...)`.

---

For the error `'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)'`, you would have to tell us exactly which resource it is failing to find.  If it is main.js, then your route handling for that resource is apparently not correct.

Comment: @KobinaTettehDadzie - Did this answer your question?